# Check return type of a function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I want to get return type of a **function**, so query will like this:

```
select t.typname
from pg_proc p
inner join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
inner join pg_type t on t.oid = p.prorettype
where n.nspname = current_schema() and p.prokind = 'f' and p.proname = 'my_function_name';
```

Now, I use `typname` to compare to get return type of function: refcursor, record, int,...
But I want to ask that I can change below query to (not join `pg_type`):

```
select p.prorettype
from pg_proc p
inner join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
where n.nspname = current_schema() and p.prokind = 'f' and p.proname = 'my_function_name'
```

So now, to check return type is refcursor, instead of `if typname = 'refcursor' then`, I will use `if prorettype = 1790 then` (1790 is `oid` of data type 'refcursor'). So can I do this? I mean, in all Postgresql version, everytime, `oid` of 'refecursor' is still 1790?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `format_type()`

```
select format_type(p.prorettype, null) as return_type
from pg_proc p
where p.proname = 'my_function_name';
  and p.pronamespace = current_schema::regnamespace;
  and p.prokind = 'f'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is the fastest way to get type of a function. In case your schema name includes uppercase characters for example, you need to change query to like this:

`select format_type(p.prorettype, null) as return_type
from pg_catalog.pg_proc p
where p.proname = 'my_function_name'
  and p.pronamespace = ('"'|| current_schema || '"')::regnamespace
  and p.prokind = 'f';`

Comment: Better use `quote_ident(current_schema)::regnamespace`